# CvVideoWriter WriteFrame for iOS not working

Tags: ios, opencv, video-capture, ogre3d

I'm using a pre-compiled version of OpenCV I got from here: http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/09/opencv-framework-for-ios/

I'm working on a Ogre3D Application, and I'm trying to grab screens from the app to stitch together to make a video. I've successfully gotten this to work on Windows using OpenCV's CvVideoWriter.

Unfortunately, I'm running into some problems on the iOS version of this. My code is as follows:

```
IplImage *mCvCaptureImage, *mCvConvertImage;
mCvCaptureImage = cvCreateImage(cvSize(width, height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
mCvConvertImage = cvCreateImage(cvSize(width, height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
PixelFormat pf = win->suggestPixelFormat();
PixelBox pb(width, height, 1, pf, mCvCaptureImage->imageData);
                    win->copyContentsToMemory(pb);
cvConvertImage(mCvCaptureImage, mCvConvertImage, CV_CVTIMG_SWAP_RB);
cvWriteFrame(writer, mCvConvertImage );
cvReleaseImage(&mCvConvertImage);
cvReleaseImage(&mCvCaptureImage);
```

The cvWriteFrame call is throwing an error due to writer status check. I checked the source code, and this seems to be the problem:

```
// writer status check
if (![mMovieWriterInput isReadyForMoreMediaData] || mMovieWriter.status !=  AVAssetWriterStatusWriting ) {
         NSLog(@"[mMovieWriterInput isReadyForMoreMediaData] Not ready for media data or ...");
         NSLog(@"mMovieWriter.status: %d. Error: %@", mMovieWriter.status,[mMovieWriter.error localizedDescription]);
         [localpool drain];
         return false;
}
```

Anyone has any ideas why this is happening and how it can be fixed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Change the file extension to m4v and delete existing file before calling cvCreateVideoWriter()

( opencv chooses filetype looking at file extension )